# Acquire raw data using OpenNI

Tags: kinect, openni, kinect-sdk

I'm using OpenNI library to work with Kinect devices and my question is the following:

Is there any way to acquire 11 bit raw depth values (0-2047) instead of real measured distance values represented in mm?

Comment: what version of OpenNI are you using and what language ?

Comment: C++ along with OpenNI 2.2